# python photometry tools

Tags: python, python-2.7

Anybody has experience with photometry? I am trying to use ppt (Python Photometric Toolbox) with no success. I have two branching questions:

- anybody can suggest a WORKING photometry solution running under Saucy Salamander
  or
- is here an experienced Python guru to help to interpret why is this message:

  ```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
      return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
      errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
      raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like it's trying to run an external command (that's sort of what subprocess does) and that's breaking.

But why is that breaking? I see no mention of cross-platform support on the Photometric Toolbox website and all the screenshots are for Windows... I would suggest it's trying to run a Windows exe (or some such) and that's exploding (as it would).

I'd punch this back to Lighting Analysts, Inc to confirm.

Not having the library (or the $250 in disposable cash to buy it) I can't really help much more than to say you *might* be able to convince certain elements to use Wine but this is going to require substantial work for a completely unguaranteed result. I'd pick another library of fold and use it on the platform it works on.

Comment: Well, this package is not made explicitly for Ubuntu, but is a Debian package: http://repos.archeos.eu/apt/pool/main/p/ppt-gui/